# Virtual Programmable Keys software for Mac?

Tags: keyboard

I've got a PC and a Macbook Pro. I use a piece of software where I frequently need to press TAB, SPACE, TAB, SPACE. So instead of hitting 4 buttons, I have a gaming keyboard which I can program to press one button and it presses those keys for me.

So now I'm on my Mac, I'm using the software but of course, I haven't got my USB gamer keyboard with me.

Is there any 'virtual' software that can do this? It would be a huge help. I've googled it but with no luck.

Comment: Did you try Automater or Apple Script?

Comment: Haven't tried them, I'll give automater a go and update you asap

Comment: Got it working with Keyboard Maestro for mac. Thanks Raindrop.